# Angularjs : Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error

Tags: angularjs

I have this angular code:

```
myApp.controller('en', [ '$scope', 'PDFViewerService', function($scope, pdf, $ionicLoading) {

                        console.log('en: new instance');

                        $scope.pdfURL = "http://www.tafseer.info/phocadownload/copy_of_the_book/khatima.pdf";//fe.toURL();

                        $scope.instance = pdf.Instance("viewer");

                        $scope.nextPage = function() {
                            $scope.instance.nextPage();
                        };

                        $scope.prevPage = function() {
                            $scope.instance.prevPage();
                        };

                        $scope.gotoPage = function(page) {
                            $scope.instance.gotoPage(page);
                        };

                        $scope.pageLoaded = function(curPage, totalPages) {
                            $scope.currentPage = curPage;
                            $scope.totalPages = totalPages;
                        };

                        $scope.loadProgress = function(loaded, total, state) {
                            console.log('loaded =', loaded, 'total =', total, 'state =', state);
                        };
}]);
```

And in my template:

```
<button ng-click="prevPage()">&lt;</button>
<button ng-click="nextPage()">&gt;</button>
<br>
<span>{{currentPage}}/{{totalPages}}</span>
<br>
<pdfviewer src="{{pdfURL}}" on-page-load='pageLoaded(page,total)' id="viewer"></pdfviewer>
```

I am trying to get a PDF file inserted into my website with AngularJS, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Error: $interpolate:interr Interpolation Error
```

Why do I get this error and how can I get rid of it? All I want is to insert the PDF...

Comment: What's PDFViewerService and pdfviewer directive?

Comment: i am use this https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code below to inject dependencies into controller is not correct.

```
myApp.controller('en', [ '$scope', 'PDFViewerService', function($scope, pdf, $ionicLoading) {
```

**List of dependencies in the array should be exact equal to function parameters**
Correct it:

```
myApp.controller('en', [ '$scope', 'PDFViewerService', 'pdf', '$ionicLoading', function($scope, 'PDFViewerService', pdf, $ionicLoading) {
```

Comment: i try your code but show me this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Comment: That is because one of the dependencies I listed  are all present in your application. I just corrected your syntax error. Make sure all PDFViewerService and pdf and $ionicLoading are present and defined.

Comment: Provide a fiddle so that would be easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is where you get the PDF, that should be in the same origin (domain) to work correctly and not in a remote location, you could try addign `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`, but again I don't think it will be sufficient to work:

```
app.controller('dummy', ['$scope', 'PDFViewerService', '$sce', function ($scope, pdf, $sce) {

    $scope.pdfURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.tafseer.info/phocadownload/copy_of_the_book/khatima.pdf"); //fe.toURL();

...
```

My suggestion is to download the PDF in a local directory and open it with pdfviewer from there.